# unable to locate package libdc1394-22-dev

Tags: apt, package-management

On Ubuntu 22.04 when I do : `sudo apt-get install libdc1394-22-dev`

I get:  `E: Unable to locate package libdc1394-22-dev`.

Can someone advise me on how to install that manually?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The `libdc1394-22-dev` package was removed in Debian and Ubuntu after 21.10.  This is because the source package it was from - `libdc1394-22` - was superseded by a different package.

The package was orphaned and removed with [Debian Bug #963924](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=963924) because the package `libdc1394` has superseded `libdc1394-22`.

It has its own dev package - `libdc1394-dev` - which will probably get you what you want/need.  So install that package instead of the package you were trying to install.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. You saved my day, cheers :-)